# Barbuttons are moving off the position

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uialertcontroller

Everything is fine until I present a `uialertcontroller`. When i present it,the `barbutton`s are moving down from thier position.

[Before presenting,everything was fine with `barbuttons`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3une.png)

[When i present an alert,you can see the `UIBarButtonItem`s are off their position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRxFf.png)

Code for creating `barbuttonitem`s::

```
let editBtn:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: IMAGE_EDIT_ICON), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleEditAction))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editBtn
```

Presenting `UIAlertControlelr` as follows:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Reset Password", message: "Please enter current password and create new password", preferredStyle: .alert)
   let okAction =  UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .default, handler: { [weak alertController] (_) in
   })


let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default) { (_) in }


alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
alertController.addAction(okAction)



okAction.isEnabled = false


alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
    textField.placeholder = "Current Password"
    }


}
alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
    textField.placeholder = "New Password"
    }


}
alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
    textField.placeholder = "Confirm Password"
    textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UITextFieldTextDidChange, object:textField,
                                           queue: OperationQueue.main) {
                                            (notification) -> Void in
                                            self.validateResetPassword(alertController: alertController,okAction: okAction)
    }



}

self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Can someone help me to fix this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: disable translucent property of naviagtion bar.

Comment: how to add navigation items through programming or interface builder .

Comment: @KKRocks Added through programming

Comment: Then replace with your button :   [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"] style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(YourSelectorTarget:)];

Comment: @KKRocks No luck :(

Comment: how to present alertview ?

Comment: `let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Reset Password", message: "Please enter current password and create new password", preferredStyle: .alert)
        


       let okAction =  UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .default, handler: { [weak alertController] (_) in
}) 
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default) { (_) in }
        
        
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: How you set bar button items? can you update with code?

Comment: set automaticallyadjustscrollviewinset as true, '[self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:YES];' . Hope it helps!!

Comment: Try `[editBtn setTitle:@" "];` title with space

Comment: @KKRocks Somehow fixed after creating barbuttons in the way you commented. Thanks.

Comment: @KKRocks  Sure. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your bar button as below :

```
let barButton =    UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "imageName"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.YourSelectorTarget))
```

Comment: Whats the  difference in your code and mine? is there any thing going wrong

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use **Interface Builder**(IB) to set `UIBarButtonItems`.
You can also set Image via IB as well as Code.

1. Set UIBarButtonItem on Interface Builder
2. Use Code:

-

```
let editBtn:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: IMAGE_EDIT_ICON), style: .plain, target: self, action:#selector(handleEditAction)) self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editBtn
```